# Elifs conditions are not working in my program

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, bioinformatics

This is my code that takes a number of codons. Codons are a group of three nucleotides, each coding for an Amino Acid
codon_sequence=[]

print("Enter no. of codons you want")

n=int(input())

for i in range(n):

```
codon=str(input())

codon_sequence.append(codon)
```

print(codon_sequence)

for i in range(n):

```
if(codon_sequence[i]=="UUU" or "UUC" or "TTT" or "TTC"):

    print("Phe_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="UUA" or "UUG" or "CUU" or "CUC" or "CUG" or "CUA" or "TTA" or "TTG" or "CTT" or "CTC" or "CTG" or "CTA"):

    print("Leu_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="UCU" or "UCC" or "UCG" or "UCA" or "AGU" or "AGC" or "TCT" or "TCC" or "TCG" or "TCA" or "AGT" or "AGC"):

    print("Ser_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="UAU" or "UAC" or "TAT" or "TAC"):

    print("Tyr_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="UGU" or "UGC" or "TGT" or "TGC"):

    print("Cys_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="UGG" or "TGG"):

    print("Trp_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="CCU" or "CCC" or "CCA" or "CCG" or "CCT"):

    print("Pro_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="CGU" or "CGC" or "CGA" or "CGG" or "AGA" or "AGG" or "CGT"):

    print("Arg_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="CAU" or "CAC" or "CAT"):

    print("His_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="CAA" or "CAG"):

    print("Gln_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="AUU" or "AUC" or "AUA" or "ATT" or "ATC" or "ATA"):

    print("Ile_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="AUG"):

    print("Met_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="ACU" or "ACC" or "ACA" or "ACG" or "ACT"):

    print("Thr_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="GUU" or "GUC" or "GUA" or "GUG" or "GTT" or "GTC" or "GTA" or "GTG"):

    print("Val_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="GCU" or "GCC" or "GCA" or "GCG" or "GCT"):

    print("Ala_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="GGU" or "GGC" or "GGA" or "GGG" or "GGT"):

    print("Gly_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="GAU" or "GAC" or "GAT"):

    print("Asp_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="GAA" or "GAG"):

    print("Glu_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="AAU" or "AAC" or "AAT"):

    print("Asn_")

elif(codon_sequence[i]=="AAA" or "AAG"):

    print("Lys_")

else:

    print("Stop_")
```

This is however, giving me only 'Phe_' as result, and ignores all other conditions

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your code is not hitting the `elif` blocks

Your `if` and `elif` blocks should look like this.
It should check if `codon_sequence[i]` is equal to a string of interest.

```
if(codon_sequence[i]=="UUU" or codon_sequence[i]=="UUC" or codon_sequence[i]=="TTT" or codon_sequence[i]=="TTC"):
```

Instead you have an `or` condition against just plain strings like `UUC`.
This will result in the first `if` condition always being `True`.
Thereby you will never hit the `elif` block.

Also a better way of writing the `if` statement would be:

```
if codon_sequence[i] in ["UUU", "UUC", "TTT", "TTC"]:
    print("Phe_")
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great candidate for a switch statement, but as the previous answer mentioned you can't put an "or" between each string like you're doing.